# Jquery selected change doesnt work on IE9?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

hi this is my click function. It works for chrome and firefox well but do anything on IE9

When i click dropdownbox dont run click function on IE9.

**Script:**

```
$('.lstKuralTipleri option').click(function() {

    switch ($('.lstKuralTipleri :selected').index()) {
    case 0:
        $('.SartliFormatDegereGore').slideDown();
        $('.SartliFormatTariheGore').slideUp();
        break;
    case 1:
        $('.SartliFormatTariheGore').slideDown();
        $('.SartliFormatDegereGore').slideUp();
        break;
    }
});​
```

**Aspx**

```
<asp:ListBox style="padding-top:3px" runat="server" ID="lstKuralTipleri" CssClass="lstKuralTipleri" Width="805px">
     <asp:ListItem Text="> Kolon değerine göre" Selected="True"/>
     <asp:ListItem Text="> Tarihe göre"/>
 </asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work ??? also, showing your HTML could really help us helping you.

Comment: i added it.click function doest work

Comment: A couple of things.  First, use 'change' instead of click.  Second, put the listener on the select box, not on the option.

Comment: @Mennan. Read my answer. and next time, please show us the **rendered HTML**

Comment: thx John Green - PageSpike and gdoron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click` event on `<option>` isn't standard and thus not supported in all browsers.
You should use the `onchange` event instead of `onclick`.

You can read all the Q&A in [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=click%20event%20option%20%5Bjavascript%5D), this is the subject for all of them...

**Updated code:**

```
$('select.lstKuralTipleri').change(function() {
    switch ($(this).index.index()) {
    case 0:
        $('.SartliFormatDegereGore').slideDown();
        $('.SartliFormatTariheGore').slideUp();
        break;
    case 1:
        $('.SartliFormatTariheGore').slideDown();
        $('.SartliFormatDegereGore').slideUp();
        break;
    }
});​
```

Comment: @Mennan. No prob. I added an updated version with the `change` event. I would have made a fiddle if I had the rendered HTML... sorry.